# Java HttpExchange: Data missing in POST Request Body

Tags: java, forms, upload, com.sun.net.httpserver

In my Java application I use the `com.sun.net.httpserver` classes for a small built-in web server. I also want to support file uploads. From a web page the user can select a file in a standard HTML form:

```
<form action="${home_url}/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="file" id="inp" name="filename" size="50"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Upload">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

In the handler for that *upload* page (where data is posted to) I do the following:

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(exchange.getRequestBody(), "utf-8");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null)
{
    parser.addLine(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

However, the first time I call `reader.readLine()` the String that I receive does not contain the first line of the original file. Instead, this first line I get in Java code is part of a line somewhere in the middle of the uploaded file.

It seems the first part of the file is lost somehow. This is reproducible, and what I get from the first `readLine()` is always the same (as always the same amount of bytes get lost during upload).

Any ideas?